# datajoint-matlab implementation of filepath@data datatype

Tags: datajoint

For datajoint-matlab, #327 seems to indicate that File external storage (#143, PR #197) should be implemented in the current version.  I can create a table with the datatype filepath@data, after defining the store 'data', but I get an error on insert.

```
Error using dj.Relvar/insert/makePlaceholder (line 244)
The field `fref` with datatype `filepath@data` is not yet supported.

Error in dj.Relvar/insert (line 334)
                    [v, placeholder] = makePlaceholder(i,
                    tuple.(header.attributes(i).name));
```

Is this still not implemented, or is the error-checking here just stopping me from using it?  Happy to provide more details on the test if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Maintainer for DataJoint here. Looks like there is a bit of confusion so let's see if I can help to bring some clarity. Hope to use this discussion as a resource to improve the documentation.

DataJoint provides a few [DataJoint-only datatypes](https://docs.datajoint.io/matlab/v3.4/definition/06-Datatypes.html#special-datajoint-only-datatypes). Of these types, we identify the ones associated with external storage by embedding an `@` symbol. We classify each part of the type as `<datatype>@<store>`. Essentially with these types, information (i.e. `datatype`) is stored remotely in an object store (i.e. a `store`) with proper reference links within the relational database and client configuration for access.

For `datatype`, there are currently 3 options:

- `blob`: Equivalent to a `blob` type but for external stores. Currently, this type is supported both in [datajoint-python](https://pypi.org/project/datajoint/#history) and most recently in [datajoint-matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/63218-datajoint).
- `attach`: A special type that captures file content as binary information but does not preserve any path information. Currently, this type is supported only in [datajoint-python](https://pypi.org/project/datajoint/#history). Documentation is available for this type in [File Attachment Datatype](https://docs.datajoint.io/matlab/v3.4/definition/06.5-External-Data.html#file-attachment-datatype) section.
- `filepath`: A special type that captures file content as binary information and includes path (along with file name) detail. Currently, this type is in preview in [datajoint-python](https://pypi.org/project/datajoint/#history) requiring it to be enabled. Documentation is available for this type in [Filepath Datatype](https://docs.datajoint.io/matlab/v3.4/definition/06.5-External-Data.html#filepath-datatype) section. See note in documentation to enable it.

For `store`, there is an [External Store](https://docs.datajoint.io/matlab/v3.4/admin/5-blob-config.html#external-store) section in the documentation. Multiple stores can be configured as a mapping located under the `stores` key in `dj.config`. For MATLAB, see `help('dj.config')` for examples and in Python, refer to the docs for `attach` and `filepath` above.

Stores currently support 2 protocols:

- `s3`: Stores objects in an S3 bucket. Currently, this store is supported both in [datajoint-python](https://pypi.org/project/datajoint/#history) and most recently in [datajoint-matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/63218-datajoint).
- `file`: Stores files in a directory accessible via the filesystem on the client. Currently, this store is supported both in [datajoint-python](https://pypi.org/project/datajoint/#history) and most recently in [datajoint-matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/63218-datajoint).

Issue [#143](https://github.com/datajoint/datajoint-matlab/issues/143) and PR's [#197](https://github.com/datajoint/datajoint-matlab/pull/197), [#327](https://github.com/datajoint/datajoint-matlab/pull/327) that you've mentioned refer to efforts in implementing `file`, `s3` stores for the `blob` datatype in DataJoint MATLAB. The error you've experienced is expected and a simple placeholder until we support the other 2 datatypes in DataJoint MATLAB.